# Remove weird border from input text field

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove a border from a input text field for my contact form.

Basically, everytime when I enter any data into the input text field (Name field) and then move on to the next field which is email, the input text field sort of has a border around it that might be invisible of some sort.

I tried my best to mess around with the CSS to make it work, but somehow its not working.

**HTML**

```
<section id="contact">
    <div class="container">
      <h3 class="contact-section-title">Need advice?</h3>
      <p class="contact-section-sub-title-form">Drop me an email below.</p
      <div class="grid-row col-2">
        <div class="grid-unit3">
          <form name="form1" method="post" action="contact.php" >
            <input name="cf_name" placeholder="What is your name? (Eg: John Doe)" type="text" required />
            <input name="cf_email" placeholder="What is your email? (Eg: johndoe@johndoe.com)" type="email" required />
            <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="cf_message" placeholder="Please enter your message" class="message" required></textarea>
            <button class="submit" type="submit">Send email</button>
            <br><Br><br><Br>
          </form>
        </div><!--class="email" type="email"-->
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24G6z/1/)

Would appreciate some solid help on this. Don't know where to go from here.

Thank you.

Comment: You've circumvented the automatic check for code by marking up an arbitrary word as code. Don't do that. Your code has to go in the question.

Comment: Last time I did put the link in the code, users couldnt click on it. My apologies on this as I'm unsure how to fix it.

Comment: You need to put the **code** in the **question**. I'm not talking about the link. You need to put actual *source code* into the question and indent *that*. You are not allowed to post JSFiddle links here without posting code as well.

Comment: I see, my apologies. Haven't used SO in a while. Will keep that in mind for future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changes I made ->

```
border:0px solid #58B9FA;
```

line 105.

Comment: You could just remove that line since it does nothing now.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is because you add `border:1px solid #58B9FA;` to all `input` element. Fix it by replacing it with:

```
input {
    border: 0
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24G6z/11/)**

Comment: @OP : also....add `outline: 0;` or `outline: none;`....or you'll hear from old IE versions!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Changed the border property in css from following

```
input {
            color: #3498db;
            display: block;
            font-family: Lato-Regular, sans-serif;
            font-size: 17px;
            margin-bottom: 0.8em;
            padding-bottom: 1em;
            padding-left: 1em;
            padding-right: 1em;
            padding-top: 1em;
            width: 100%;
            border:1px solid #58B9FA; }
```

to

```
input {
        color: #3498db;
        display: block;
        font-family: Lato-Regular, sans-serif;
        font-size: 17px;
        margin-bottom: 0.8em;
        padding-bottom: 1em;
        padding-left: 1em;
        padding-right: 1em;
        padding-top: 1em;
        width: 100%;
        border:0px solid #58B9FA; }
```

Answer (score 1):

set  `border: none;` or `border:0` in your `input` css

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/24G6z/12/)